# How to deserialize a file received from the network

Tags: c#, serialization, tcpclient

I'm working on a software i need some help.

I have a client and server. Server will serialize a text file and send it to the client.

My current progress: Client receiving binary array but can't write it to disc as original text file.

```
private void ListenPort()
{
    TcpListener _TcpListener= new _TcpListener(7381);
    byte[] received_binary= new byte[1024];

    _TcpListener.Start();
    while (true) 
    { 
        Socket Soket = _TcpListener.AcceptSocket();
        Soket.Receive(received_binary, received_binary.Length, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655980/how-to-receive-a-file-over-tcp-which-was-sent-using-socket-filesend-method

Comment: What happens currently? What behaves in a way different to what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to deserialize it to string? Here is a function I wrote a while ago which may help...

```
 public static T BinaryDeserializeObject<T>(byte[] serializedType)
    {
        if (serializedType == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("serializedType");

        if (serializedType.Length.Equals(0))
            throw new ArgumentException("byte array cannot be empty"));

        T deserializedObject;

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(serializedType))
        {
            BinaryFormatter deserializer = new BinaryFormatter();
            deserializedObject = (T)deserializer.Deserialize(memoryStream);
        }

        return deserializedObject;
    }
```

Comment: Before jumping to BinaryFormatter, I would suggest asking the OP what it means to "serialize a text file". A file is, after all, already fully serialized. This data would typically just be the raw bytes of the file.

Comment: The BinaryFormatter performance is really terrible. There are superior serialisers such as protobuf-net if that's what you're after.

Comment: Yep, Im a huge fan of protobuf-net which I believe Marc Gravell (above) wrote - I've been using it for some seriously heavy stuff recently and it just performs! 
The code I posted is out of an ancient library I wrote when I first started with c#, but the Op did say he recieved a binary array which he couldn't convert to a string and this code will do the job of converting it.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue seems to be that you are ignoring the return value from receive. This returns the number of bytes in each read. You should loop until this is non-positive, each time processing (for example writing to a FileStream) that many bytes (only: even if the buffer is larger).

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to load the text file either as a series of strings or as a byte array and send that. The byte array approach might be the most concise and efficient, as it can be compressed during send, using the [network library networkcomms.net](http://www.networkcomms.net) the application calling the sending would look something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using NetworkCommsDotNet;

namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] bytesToSend = File.ReadAllBytes("testFile.txt");
            TCPConnection.GetConnection(new ConnectionInfo("127.0.0.1", 10000)).SendObject("TextFileData", bytesToSend);

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit client.");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            NetworkComms.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

and the server:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using NetworkCommsDotNet;

namespace Server
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NetworkComms.AppendGlobalIncomingPacketHandler<byte[]>("TextFileData", (packetHeader, connection, incomingData) => 
            {
                    Console.WriteLine("Received TextFileData");
                    File.WriteAllBytes("testFile.txt", incomingData);
            });

            TCPConnection.StartListening(true);

            Console.WriteLine("Server ready. Press any key to shutdown server.");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            NetworkComms.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

You will obviously need to download the NetworkCommsDotNet DLL from the website so that you can add it in the 'using NetworkCommsDotNet' reference. Also see the server IP address in the client example is currently "127.0.0.1", this should work if you run both the server and client on the same machine. For more information also checkout the [getting started](http://www.networkcomms.net/getting-started/) or [how to create a client server application](http://www.networkcomms.net/how-to-create-a-client-server-application-in-minutes/) articles.