# How to transfer a file by socket PHP to C#

Tags: c#, php, sockets

Hi after a lot of research i didn't found a solution to my case

I have a C# socket server what's is running on my server and i need to transfer files to it by Socket from my website that's in PHP.

What i have now ?

Php part:

```
    $file = array('file' => Input::file('file'));
    $fp = stream_socket_client("tcp://localhost:9192", $error_number, $error_string);
    if ( !$fp ) {
        echo "$error_number ($error_string)\n";
    } else {
        fwrite($fp, $file['file']);    
    }

    fclose($fp);
```

C# Socket Server:

```
        String content = String.Empty;

        // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
        // from the asynchronous state object.
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;

        // Read data from the client socket. 
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

            // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read 
            // more data.
            content = state.sb.ToString();
            if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
            {
                // All the data has been read from the 
                // client. Display it on the console.
                Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}",
                    content.Length, content);
                // Echo the data back to the client.
                Send(handler, content);
            }
            else
            {
                // Not all data received. Get more.
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
            }
        }
```

When i try to make the connection the C# instantly refuses it what i'm doing wrong ?

I'm using Laravel 5 on PHP part.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in this question:

[How to receive a file over TCP which was sent using socket.FileSend Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655980/how-to-receive-a-file-over-tcp-which-was-sent-using-socket-filesend-method)

Sorry for waste your time :)